# Deletion of a String of varying Numbers in many cells

Tags: format

I have a problem.

I have a google spreadsheet, with 22594 rows of data. Among the Data displayed in these rows, is one column indicating the date of birth. Sadly, whoever compiled the data, didn't do it right. So here is a example of one of the cells that should display just the date of birth:"1964-08-23 17:32:02.188Z", what I need to do is delete the string of numbers after the date, which is different in each row. I also need to change the format of the date, so it is "DD-MM-YYYY" instead of "YYYY-MM-DD". Anybody know any trick how I could manage that?

I tried asking Chat-GPT for solutions, but nothing it suggested worked.